# I'm getting an error that says method in class cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

```
I'm new to Java inheritance. I am getting this error
```

CylinderArea.java:21: error: method getRadius in class CircleArea cannot be applied to given types;
return (2*Math.PI*getRadius()*height)+(2*super.findArea());
^

here is my code for the super class

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class CircleArea{
  private double radius;

  public CircleArea(){ //default
      radius = 10.22;
  }

  public CircleArea(double r){ //constructor with value
      radius = r;
  }

  public double getRadius(){
      return radius;
  }

  public double findArea(){
      return Math.PI*radius*radius;
  }

  public String toString(){
      DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###,###,##");
      return "\nThe radius of the Circle is: "+radius
          +   "\nThe area of the Circle is: "+df.format(findArea());
  }

}
```

this is the sub class

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat; 

public class CylinderArea extends CircleArea{
  private double height;

  public CylinderArea(){
      super();
      height = 22.50;
  }

  public CylinderArea(double r, double h){
      super(r);
      height = h;
  }

  public double getHeight(){
      return height;
  }

  public double findArea(){
      return (2*Math.PI*getRadius()*height)+(2*super.findArea());
  }

  public String toString(){
      DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###,###.##");
      return "\nThe radius of the Cylinder is: "+getRadius()
          +   "\nThe area of the Cylinder is: "+df.format(findArea()); 
  }
}
```

and this is the main

```
public class TestInheritance{

  public static void main(String []args){
    CircleArea c1 = new CircleArea();
    CylinderArea cy1 = new CylinderArea();

    System.out.println(c1);
    System.out.println(cy1);
  }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: `getRadius` returns a double. So in your `toString` function, may be you just need to do `getRadius().toString()` ?

Comment: I already solved it! Thank you. There was nothing wrong with the code. It turns out, my class file was missing from the folder where I put all my codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried the same code in my ide(Eclipse) and does not get any error.

[Given Code Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSvV5.png)

Comment: You can try code that edited by Nisanth Reddy.

Comment: I already solved it! Thank you. There was nothing wrong with the code. It turns out, my class file was missing from the folder where I put all my codes.

Comment: You should mark one of the answers as Accepted by clicking the green checkmark.  I wish you good work.